# CanActivate: Converting Observable<Observable<boolean>> to Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables, canactivate

I have a user settings page that only the owner should have access to. I want to use CanActivate to implement the restriction. CanActivate requires the output to be boolean or the observable of a boolean. However, my code outputs an observable of an observable of a boolean.

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
```

> Here my code

```
@Injectable()
export class UserGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  canActivate() {
    const username = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('username');

    return this.userService.authState().map(auth => {
      return this.userService.getByUid(auth.uid).map(user => {
        return user.username === username ? true : false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.switchMap` in order to flatten the observable. Read about it more here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Essentially if you chain `.switchMap` to a source observable and an inner observable is returned, *that* observable will be subscribed to and its value emitted rather than the observable itself being emitted:

```
return this.userService.authState().switchMap(auth => {
```

In this case you can also flatten your code slightly by chaining `.map` to the original observable stream.

```
return this.userService.authState().switchMap(auth =>
  this.userService.getByUid(auth.uid)
).map(user => user.username === username);
```